# Mysql temporary, filesort issue

Tags: mysql, indexing, temp-tables, filesort

From my research, I'm not even sure it is possible to avoid the temporary / filesort with the following query due to the group by and order by. I'm also not one to ask without doing a ton of research on my own. But if anyone can help figure out how to avoid the filesort or point me in the correct direction - even if its completely re-writing the query or suggesting something code side, it would be much appreciated. I've completely hit a wall trying to figure this one out. There's a link to the output of the explain at the bottom.

```
explain select CONCAT(scfs.name, ' ',scfs.state,' ',scfs.zip_code) as scfname, scfs.zip_code, IF(date(s.scan_datetime) <= date(NOW()),date(s.scan_datetime),null) as scandate, count(*) as total,
                    sum(case when s.delivery_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as final

                     from order_addresses oa
                         left join pkg_data_unique s
                            on oa.trace_code = s.pkg_trace_code
                         inner join scf_zip_codes z
                            on SUBSTR(oa.zip,1,3) = z.zip_code
                         inner join scfs scfs
                            on z.scf_zip_code = scfs.zip_code



                    where oa.order_id = 160387

                    group by 1,2,3
                    order by scfs.zip_code, scandate
```

CREATE ORDER ADDRESSES

`CREATE TABLE order_addresses (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    order_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    address varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    address2 varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    city varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    state varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    zip char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    zip4 int(11) NOT NULL,
    imb_digits char(31) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    trace_code char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY order_address_unique 
    (order_id,imb_digits,name,address,address2,city,state,zip),
    KEY order_addresses_order_id_index (order_id),
    KEY order_addresses_name_index (name),
    KEY order_addresses_address_index (address),
    KEY order_addresses_city_index (city),
    KEY order_addresses_state_index (state),
    KEY order_addresses_zip_index (zip),
    KEY order_addresses_imb_digits_index (imb_digits),
    KEY order_addresses_trace_code_index (trace_code),
    KEY order_id_trace_code (order_id,trace_code) USING BTREE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=487714542 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`

PKG DATA UNIQUE TABLE

`CREATE TABLE pkg_data_unique (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  zip char(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  opcode int(11) NOT NULL,
  pkg_trace_code char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  scan_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
  original_scan_datetime datetime NOT NULL,
  delivery_status int(11) NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY pkg_data_unique_pkg_trace_code_index (pkg_trace_code) USING BTREE,
  KEY pkg_data_unique_zip_index (zip),
  KEY pkg_data_unique_opcode_index (opcode),
  KEY pkg_data_unique_scan_datetime_index (scan_datetime),
  KEY pkg_data_unique_delivery_status_index (delivery_status),
  KEY pkg_data_unique_original_scan_datetime (original_scan_datetime)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=490667214 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`

SCF ZIP CODES

`CREATE TABLE scf_zip_codes (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  scf_zip_code varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  zip_code varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY scf_zip_codes_scf_zip_code_index (scf_zip_code),
  KEY scf_zip_codes_zip_code_index (zip_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=916 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`

SCFS

`CREATE TABLE scfs (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  label_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  zip_code varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  state varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  locale_key varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY scfs_label_id_unique (label_id),
  UNIQUE KEY scfs_zip_code_unique (zip_code),
  KEY scfs_name_index (name),
  KEY scfs_state_index (state)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=196 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`

[Image of Explain Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MPO9.png)

Comment: please add *show create table* for each table

Comment: Added the show create tables for each table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> figure out how to avoid the filesort or point me in the correct direction

The alternative(s) involve changing the intent of your query.

```
    group by  1,2,3
    order by  scfs.zip_code, scandate
```

The `GROUP BY` may involve a filesort an temp table.

The `ORDER BY` will certainly involve (another) filesort and temp table because it does not match the `GROUP BY`.  No, shuffling to `GROUP BY 2,1,3` (since col 2 is the zip code) won't help.

If you can live with this, `GROUP BY 2,1,3  ORDER BY 2,1,3`, then you can get rid of one filesort and have approximately the same output.

Is your query "slow"?  'Filesort' is not the main performance killer.

There are a few things that can speed up the query some:

- Zipcodes (and some other things) don't need utf8; change the column to `CHARACTER SET ascii`.
- Secondary keys, when used, need to drill down the `PRIMARY KEY` BTree to find the row.  Consider which, if any, secondary indexes could be promoted to `PRIMARY KEY`.
- `date(s.scan_datetime) <= date(NOW())` --> `s.scan_datetime <= CURDATE()`
- `sum(case when s.delivery_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end)` => `sum(case when s.delivery_status = 1)` since a boolean expression evaluates to 1 or 0.
- `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)` --> the first can be `DROPped` without loss of functionality.
- `scfs` has 3 unique keys; `id` seems useless.  Promote `zipcode` to be the PK and make it `CHAR(5) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  It will be 5 bytes instead of id's 4 bytes.
- Don't blindly use `(255)`; pick a smaller (but safe) value.

Comment: Better late than never on the accept. Just logged in for the first time in a while and this definitely helped when you answered. Sorry for the delay